# Action Variable not accepted

Tags: php

I have used this code a million times before but now I'm having problems.

in my top.php file I have put the code as http://www.sentuamsg.com/index.php?action=about

now when I reach my index page I get an error code of Notice: Undefined variable: action in /home/content/90/9753290/html/index.php on line 4

```
<?php
include("top.php");

if($action == "") {

echo "<p align=center><img src=mondaymoan.jpg></img></p>";

echo "<p><font face=Tahoma><b><font size=2>Monday Moan:</font></b> <font size=2>
All the weeks Gaming Action, Rumours, News snipplets assessed and talked about 
all in one blog. Have a read of your own on this Monday's Moan</font></font></p>";

echo "<p align=right><font face=Tahoma size=2>[Read]</font></p>";

echo "<p><img src=mostloved.jpg></p>";

echo "<p align=center><img src=retrogamer.jpg></img></p>";

echo "<p><font face=Tahoma><b><font size=2>Retro Gamer:</font></b> <font size=2>
Taking on the games from the past, these games range from Video Game consoles to PC Games. One of our most popular feature as you the gamers relive the past with us through the joys and frustrations.</font></font></p>";

echo "<p align=right><font face=Tahoma size=2>[View]</font></p>";

include("bottom.php");
exit;
}

if($action == "action") {

echo "done";

include("bottom.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Why is this error happening? Am I missing something or am I using very old coding techniques that isn't used in php5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you haven't set `$action` before trying to use it. The following line of code needs to go above you `if($action == "") {` statement:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];
```

Or, better yet, you should check to see if it exists first:

```
$action = (isset($_GET['action'])) ? $_GET['action'] : '';
```

Comment: that was perfect, honestly haven't coded for over 6 years. Thanks for that have tried researching this for days with no luck so this is very appreciated

Comment: Please accept the answer if it has solved your problem. You might want to research `REGISTER_GLOBALS` (that is why your code is not working like before)

Answer (score 0):

you should use `$_GET["action"]` and read this ; [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php)